# IIS Recycle kills Kestrel - can I set the IIS recycle to never for ASP.NET Core Applications?

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, iis-8

unfortunately our production site dies every time IIS recycles the APP pool after 29 hours (default recycle phase). It seems like the entire application gets into a stall and becomes unresponsive. In most cases I need to restart the entire server.

Our site is an ASP.NET Core app running on Elastic Beanstalk and right now I do a preventive url/server swap every night - just in case.

As Kestrel doesn't need recycling but needs a reverse proxy to start it up I was wondering if I could set the IIS recycle period to **never** to solve the problem.

I can't see anything in the logs that shows a problem. 
Also, whenever it happens the server is running on low CPU and nothing seems to be going on at all.

Thank you for your help!

Best,
H

Comment: I'm not familiar with EB, but can you access IIS Manager on the server? You can disable recycling on the app pool running the website via right-click on it and selecting "Recycling".

Answer (score 0):

In the .ebextensions folder add a file named iis-settings.config with the contents:

```
commands:
    setIdleTimeoutToZero:
        cwd: "C:\\windows\\system32\\inetsrv"
        command: "appcmd set apppool /apppool.name:DefaultAppPool /.processModel.idleTimeout:0.00:00:00"
    setPeriodicRecycleToZero:
        cwd: "C:\\windows\\system32\\inetsrv"
        command: "appcmd set apppool /apppool.name:DefaultAppPool /.recycling.periodicRestart.time:00:00:00"
```

See here for more details on ebextensions https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/ebextensions.html